# paginate_links does not display the second page

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I want to create a blog page displaying only 5 posts per page and if there are 7 posts the last two posts will display on the second page.

Here is what I have got so far:

```
<div style="float:left; padding-top: 20px;">
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '','post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date", 'cat'=>1,'paged' => get_query_var('paged'));
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
?>
<div style="float:left;" class="three columns">

    <label style="color:#DB6903;"><?php the_date(); ?></label>
    <?php the_author(); ?><br>
    <?php comments_number(); ?>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>


<div style="float:left; padding-top: 10px; " class="eight columns" >

    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent" style="color: black;">
        <h2 style="font-size: 28px;"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </a>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <p>         <?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

    </div>
        <img src="wp-content/themes/quaero/images/grey_divider" width="100%"  alt="divider" />
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</div><aside style="float:left; padding-left: 20px;" class="one-third columns">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</aside><div style="clear:both;"></div><?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
```

When I click on the second page, it doesn't display the last two posts. It still displays the first 5 posts. How can I fix this?

Update:
Now `posts_nav_link()` works. But the navigation displays "« Previous Page Next Page »" even after the second page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query `$args` doesn't contain paged parameter.

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '','post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",
  'orderby'=>"post_date", 'cat'=>1,'paged' => get_query_var('paged'));
```

Comment: Blog page have 11 posts.But the navigation shows "1 2 3 4 Next »" Why is it so?

Comment: Something seems goes wrong for `total` variable. Check what you getting for `$wp_query->max_num_pages` ? It should be `11`.

Comment: Can you please check updated code above? Now i'm using posts_nav_link() and not using base_pagination() in functions.php

Comment: @Veena  It will just display `Next` & `Prev` right ? Not displaying it ?

Comment: It is displaying all the 7 posts(5 posts per page). Problem is that there is "Next" in the second page and navigates to an empty page (there is only two pages to display. Then how "next" comes???)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27540/discussion-between-rikesh-and-veena)